# SQL Timekeeping Subtraction

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a timekeeping table which shows me (a)Dates, (b)Clock in time by employees & (c) clock out time by employees.
Time format is in HH/MM/SS
I would like some assistance on subtraction of time (to get the time difference) where;

Date column will stay fixed.
Normal daily start time need to be subtracted with the clock in time (so 8 or 8:00:00 - clock in time)
Clock out time need to be subtracted with the normal daily end time (Clock out time - 17:00:00)

I then want to add the difference of both to make 1 column which will show Overtime or Under time for a specific day. (so to get the Net values for time)

End result then just to have 4 tables; (1)Date, (2)Clock In, (3)CLock Out, (4)Over/under time.

Thanks in advance
Marius

Comment: This is for a work dashboard project.I am currently reviewing other possibilities. I think it might be better to sum total hours worked, from clock in to clock out seeing as some employees clock in and out more then once a day, which might give incorrect details with above reflection.So total hours worked per day vs. standard 8h30m required

Answer (score 0):

Just alter your database to just contain four fields:

```
id (int) PK    
employee_id (int) ix
clock_in (datetime)  
clock_out (datetime)
```

Then you can do some nice conversions with the [date & time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) of MySQL. Just try to keep your database as clean (and normalized) as possible.

(
Look at the right data-type of the clock_* fields. I'm normally using Postgres and they have the data-types mixed:
`timestamp` in postgres is a real date-time like `2014-04-16 10:40:06` whereas a `timestamp` in mysql is the unix timestamp, the number of seconds since the unix start somewhere in 1970.
)